# JOIN inside WHERE vs outside WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Will both statements return the same results?

The top code has the JOIN in the WHERE clause and takes over 4 hrs to run. By moving the JOIN outside the WHERE the same query runs in 1m 6s. I have not seen a JOIN in a WHERE clause.

**Note** DSA.doc_id is a child version record of orders.folder.

```sql
    --OLD CODE TAKING 4+ HRS TO RUN
    SELECT top 1 status_to_date
    FROM DSA
    WHERE (status_to = 'CA') 
    and left(DSA.doc_id,12) = orders.folder 


    --NEW CODE TAKING LESS THAN A MINUTE
    SELECT top 1 status_to_date
    FROM DSA
    left outer join orders 
        on left(DSA.doc_id,12) = orders.folder 
    WHERE (status_to = 'CA')
```

Comment: Your first statement is not syntactically correct, so the two are not equivalent.  In any case, always use `explicit` joins.

Comment: Applying functions to columns prevents the optimizer from using indexes. In the second case the optimizer was able to convert your equality to a range query, which is why it was faster. If you found a way to get rid of `Left`, so that the join used true equality, your statement would probalby run in seconds

Comment: To see what's different you need to check the execution plans of the two queries. The SQL statement itself isn't enough

Comment: to which table belong status_to_date and status_to?

Answer (score 2):

Yes I believe both queries will give same result.  And in side where join gives slowest result. But there is one more alternate of above query which willl be nmore and more faster then second query too

```
Select 
     Top (1) status_to_date
 FROM 
    DSA
 WHERE 
    (status_to = 'CA')
    AND  (Select count(*) From orders where orders.folder =  left(DSA.doc_id,12)) > 0
```